# Google App Engine - get_serving_url - how do i immediately remove access to an image in the case of a DMCA takedown notice?

Tags: google-app-engine

When you use get_serving_url, it creates a url for serving the image. However, according to http://ikaisays.com/2010/09/08/gwt-blobstore-the-new-high-performance-image-serving-api-and-cute-dogs-on-office-chairs/

> Deleting an image blob doesn’t delete
>   the image being served from the URL
>   right away – that image will still be
>   available for some time

If I get a [DMCA takedown notice](http://chillingeffects.org/dmca512/) for the image, it's important to remove access right away. So is there a way I can remove access quickly?

Comment: Not a lawyer, but could you inform the sender of the takedown notice that Google has cached the image, that the cache will expire in due course, that you have no technical ability to flush the cache, and that if they want to issue an additional takedown notice to Google (or anyone else who is publishing their copyright image), they know the address? ;-)

Comment: @steve Probably that would be fine, but it would be nice to be on the safe side and not cause the copyright holder any extra undue hassle which might be argued in court that I wasn't following the proper procedure or something.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to immediately remove access you'll need to serve the image directly from your app instead of using get_serving_url.